# Cannot find 'Submission.csv' File in 'Google Colab

Tags: python, model, google-colaboratory, submission, predictive

I have run a predictive model in Google Colab and saved the 'Submission.csv' file. Now I don't know how to locate the file on colab and upload it to the comp. site. Can anyone advice please and thank you.

The submission file was saved but I cannot locate it.

This was the line of code used to save the file in google colab:

sub.to_csv(f"./harvest_sample_submission.csv", index = False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to download the csv file to your computer from colab

```
from google.colab import files
files.download(f"./harvest_sample_submission.csv")
```

Also, you can open left side bar with folder icon, and the csv file can be located their.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can find your file on the side tab (find the figure).